# Android : How to stop all threads start in fragment when change fragment

Tags: android

I have an activity with many fragments inside. In one fragment, I run some periodically thread that use some command such as `getActivity().runOnUiThread()`, so when switch to different fragmemnt, those statement will make `NullPointException`.

I know how to stop a thread, but don't know which method to put this code inside. (it means: when switch fragment, which method that fragment will always run before switch).

Please help me about this problem.

Thanks :)

Comment: @Leco the post below said `onDetach()` is there any difference between those ? Thanks :)

Comment: Yes. onPause() is called prior to onDetach(), which is the last method called on the Fragment's lifecycle. See here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle

Comment: @Leco oh. nice. in this chart, really `onPause` is the best way :)

Comment: can you please tell me what is the code to stop getActivity().runOnUiThread() these threads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to help of Leco. The best way is put those code into `onPause`.

You can see more detail in this link: [Fragment Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle)

Help this post will useful for anyone meets same problem with me.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting it in `onDetach()`.